# Getting empty query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to get a PDO query running, so I'm doing:

```
$src = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, model, software FROM product WHERE 
                             model LIKE '%:search_string%' OR 
                             name LIKE '%:search_string%' OR 
                             software LIKE '%:search_string%'");
$src->bindParam(':search_string', $search_string);
$src->execute();
return $src->fetchAll();
```

But when I `var_dump` this, I always get an empty array ( `[]` ). However, if I change it to just "`SELECT name, model, software FROM product`", I get all of the products, just as expected, so how am I using the `LIKE` clause wrong? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: @AnotherCode Yep that did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bound parameters cannot be used in this way. You have to input it as `LIKE :search_string` in the prepared query, then add the percent signs in the bound value (i.e. `$src->bindParam(':search_string', '%' . $search_string . '%');`).

See also this [comment on PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698).

Comment: Yep, I did it when you linked me that documentation! Likes to you sir, as soon as the timer is off (6 minutes), I'll accept the answer.